# Create a new array from objects inside objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this:

```
data=[
  {
    test1:{a: ""}
  },
  {
    test2: {a: ""}
  }
]
```

How can I convert it to this:

```
data=[
  {
    test1:{a: ""},
    test2:{a: ""}
  }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: The objects inside the original array always just have 1 key, and its unique across the entire set?

Comment: `data = [Object.assign(...data)]`